# Onepage checkout not proceeding to the next step

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

When clicking on the continue button of the onepage checkout page, the next step does not load and the page get stuck there. I inspected the page using Chrome Inspect option and saw these errors:

```
form.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined
at t.init (form.js:41)
at t.initialize (form.js:37)
at t (prototype.js:1)
at (index):1426  

init @ form.js:41 initialize @ form.js:37
t @ prototype.js:1
(anonymous) @ (index):1426

popup.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at popup.js:2
(anonymous) @ popup.js:2


  prototype.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
  at t.initialize (prototype.js:1)
  at new t (prototype.js:1)
  at t.save (opcheckout.js:361)
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):609)
```

Now I do not know how to correct these errors, but I feel these are causing the page to stuck. Some help would be highly appreciated.

My website : http://makimus.com

Thank you!

Comment: First check your `prototype.js`. there is missing brackets. Add brackets then try

Comment: Two different versions of jQuery are loaded. This might cause a conflict. Only load one version.

Comment: on your website their's an error saying $ is not defined please place your 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js' file before including any scripts, i mean at the top of other javascript files

Comment: Can you please tell me how to load only one?

Comment: Ok I will try to place that jquery on top.

Comment: Does checkout work when disabling social login extension? This is adding another jQuery version.

Comment: As said by @Gerard de Visser,  remove other jquery files only include the one with latest version in your project

Comment: I've posted an answer with explanation.

Comment: @Gerard de Visser I have disabled social login extension. Now the first set of error : uncaught type error cannot read has disappeared but the ------  popup.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at popup.js:2
(anonymous) @ popup.js:2
prototype.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
    at t.initialize (prototype.js:1)
    at new t (prototype.js:1)
    at t.save (opcheckout.js:361)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):609) is still present

Comment: The jQuery of social login is still loaded. Have you cleaned the cache?

Comment: Just cleared the cache. You may please check now.

Comment: jQuery is still loaded as you can see in console. Please follow instructions of the answer I've posted.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser there is an option in social login extension of Allow Add jquery library... I just put that to no. Shall i keep it to no or to yes? If it has something with the issue.

Comment: Please set it to no.

Comment: @KunvarAishwary there is still missing one bracket `)` in `prototype.js` add it so multiple errors can be removed from console. Last line should be `}()})(jquery);`

Comment: @B.Desai now I have added that bracket too, but still i am seeing the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at popup.js:2    -   and also after clicking continue button on checkout this error in console of inspect appears -----  Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
    at t.initialize (prototype.js:1)
    at new t (prototype.js:1)
    at t.save (opcheckout.js:361)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):605)

Comment: @ChaitanyaGhule How to move jquery-1.11.1.min.js to the top? PLease help a bit.

Comment: just place it before prototype.js and check for other errors in console inorder to resolve your issue step by step. thanks..

Comment: as their are many js files we can't exactly predict what's the issue. so, first inorder to start debbuging your code check whether jquery-x.y.z.js file is placed at the the begining or not. sometimes, it happens that due to just misplacement of jquery file we get too many errors even if their are no error in other included scripts. hope, u got what i want to say

Answer (score 1):

Two different versions of jQuery are loaded. This might cause a conflict. In your case social login is adding another jQuery version.

Find the layout file at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout` and copy it to `app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/[your_package]/layout` and remove the part that loads jQuery.

Comment: sorry, but which layout file I need to copy?

Comment: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/magecheckout/sociallogin.xml` to `app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/[your_package]/layout/magecheckout/sociallogin.xml`

Comment: copied! Now, is there something else to be done in addition?

Comment: Remove the part from xml that loads jQuery.